# How will Concepts-Lite interact with variadic templates?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

I watched Bjarne Strustrup's talk in [Going Native 2013](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Opening-Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup) and he gives the following example for the upcoming concepts-lite feature of C++.

```
void sort(Container& c); // terse notation

// Expands to
template <Container __Cont>
  void sort(__Cont& c); // shorthand notation

// Expands to 
template <typename __Cont>
  requires Container<__Cont>()
    void sort(__Cont & c);
```

My question is how will this work with variadic templates?

Say I want to define a variadic `maximum` function using a `Comparable` concept. Will the following syntax be accepted?

```
auto maximum(Comparable a)
{
     return a;
}

auto maximum(Comparable c, Comparable... rest)
{        
    return std::max(a, maximum(rest...));
}
```

If so will `Comparable...` mean that all the elements in the parameter pack are the same type or just that they are all `Comparable` types so that the pack may include both `int` and `string`? (which are both comparable but not to each other)

Curious minds want to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the intention of the terse format is to require all elements in the pack must be of the same type. This is derived from the example in n3701 §5.3, which states that

```
void sort(Random_access_iterator p, Random_access_iterator q);
```

should be equivalent to

```
template<Random_access_iterator __Ran>
void sort(__Ran p, __Ran q);
```

because

> "By default, if you use the same constrained parameter
>   type name for two arguments, the types of those arguments must be the same.
>   We chose to make repeated use of a constrained parameter type name imply
>   “same type” because that (in most environments) is the most common case,
>   it would be odd to have an identifier used twice in a scope have two different
>   meanings, and the aim here is to optimize for terse notation of the simplest case."

But I don't see how it can be expanded into your `maximum` with the current ('14) template syntax.  In proposed change of standard wording in n3701 it only talked about the simple case

> ### §7.1.6.5 Constrained type specifiers [dcl.spec.constrained]
>
> ...
>
> The first use of *concept-name* or *partial-concept-id* within a scope binds that
>   name to the placeholder type so that subsequent uses of the same name refer to
>   the same type.

But it doesn't explain the interaction of variadics. Maybe need to wait for the 3rd revision to clarify this.

Comment: In the OPs example it's not just the parameter pack, but also the first parameter. Your answer also leaves the question to the authors of Concepts how to write a function like `void sort( Iterator a, Iterator b );` when I explicitly want `a` and `b` to be allowed to have different types. Hm. I have to admit I was never a fan of Concepts... :-/

Comment: @DanielFrey: If you need `a` and `b` to be different, don't use the terse form. `template <Iterator A, Iterator B> void sort(A a, B b);`.

Comment: @DanielFrey: And also I can't think of how to write `auto maximum(Comparable c, Comparable... rest)` into `template <????> auto (???? c, ????... rest);` while requiring all of `c` and `rest...` to have the same type, thus the last sentence in the answer.

Comment: @KennyTM `require` that the pack is full of the same type, and that if non empty, an instance of that type matches the requirement.  Not hard with concepts, but a more complex transformation than the non variardic case.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if [N3580](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf) is the latest version of the concept paper but in 4.5.1 it seems to describe how type requirements can be used with variadic argument lists. It seems that

```
template <Comparable... T>
auto maximum(T... values) -> <return-type-goes-here>
```

would require that each of the arguments satisfies the `Comparable` requirement but there is no restriction that the types `T...` are all the same. This requirement would need to be imposed separately. Off-hand, the only way I'd know how to impose the same type requirement is the same approach as in C++11 but the concepts facilities may have a better approach.

Comment: Doesn't C++14 allow for implicit return types for `auto` so no need for <return-type-goes-here>?

Comment: @Motti: it depends on how your function is written if I recall correctly. Given that the types are all different I'm not quite sure you can the compiler just have it work out.

Comment: Yeah well the whole point of my question was to ask _whether_ the types are different.

Comment: @Motti: ... and I think I have answered it: "... but there is no restriction that the types `T...` are all the same"

Comment: N3701 is a later version: (013-06-28)
http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3701.pdf