# Did template concepts get to c++14?

Tags: c++, c++14

Concepts is nice feature that for example replaces ugly compiler error output when something is wrong with template instantiation with nice readable messages.
Unfortunately they did not get [to C++11](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#what-concepts)

Does anybody know if it made it to C++14?

Comment: Not sure, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811772/how-will-c14-concepts-lite-interact-with-variadic-templates

Comment: Hmm...no C++1y tag anymore?

Comment: @0x499602D2 C++14 was approved yesterday: https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/08/we-have-cpp14

Comment: Next year, according to https://isocpp.org/std/status

Comment: `std::enable_if` can give you readable error messages. See [here](http://pfultz2.com/blog/2014/08/17/type-requirements/). Also `static_assert` works really well for readable messages.

Answer (score 7):

No, but [this interview with Bjarne Strostrup](http://electronicdesign.com/dev-tools/bjarne-stroustrup-talks-about-c14) says that they will be put into "Technical Specifications" that implementors may use.

Comment: TSs don't write into namespace `std`. They go in `std::experimental`.