# In what form are "concepts" implemented in the finalized C++14 spec?

Tags: c++, c++14

[C++14 was finalized](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/08/we-have-cpp14) two days ago. Concepts were a hotly debated topic for inclusion into C++11, and when they couldn't be implemented in time for that release, they were pushed back to C++1y (which we now know as C++14).

In what form did concepts end up? Did we get full "concepts" as originally envisioned? Or "concepts-lite"? Or no concepts at all?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of a question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25387888/10077

Comment: The form of concepts we have in C++11/14 are just the type traits and `enable_if`. See [here](http://pfultz2.com/blog/2014/08/17/type-requirements/) on how to write concept predicates in C++11/14.