# template for "AnySTLContainer<int>" c++

Tags: c++, templates, stl, template-argument-deduction

I am looking for a way to provide a function that takes a templated (STL) container, but requires its elements to be of a certain type (e.g. `int`).

These function calls should be VALID:

```
std::vector<int> Argument;
void foo( Argument );

std::list<int> Argument
void foo( Argument );

std::deque<int> Argument
void foo( Argument );

...etc
```

These function calls should be INVALID:

```
std::vector<float> Argument;
void foo( Argument );

std::list<double> Argument
void foo( Argument );

std::deque<char> Argument
void foo( Argument );

...etc
```

Is there a way to template "foo" such that containers of `int` are accepted, but containers with different element types are not accepted ?

Best,
Ben

Comment: Just checking, do you really need a *container*? Do mere iterators not work?

Comment: BTW: Must it be a standard-library container, or is any kind of conainer of `int` good enough? Maybe even immutable sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use Sfinae, like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename Container>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< typename Container::value_type, int >::value,
void >::type foo(Container& c) {
  /* code here */
};
```

Which will be removed from the set of overloads of "foo" if the container does not have a value type that is the same as "int". You can also use other traits, like `is_convertible` for being more accepting of related types. Calling foo with a container that does not have int as values will be reported by the compiler has having no suitable overload candidates.

If you don't have C++11 support, the things I used above are available in Boost as a C++98/03 alternative.

Answer (score 14):

Use the Standard Library semantics :

- Pass a pair of iterators to `foo`, not a container : it makes your function **much** more generic
- Use `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type` to get to the value type
- `static_assert` the value type of the Iterator to be an `int` (or whatever type you want)

**Example :**

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>

template<typename Iterator>
void foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<int, typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>::value, 
                                "Invalid value type : must be int");
}

int main() {
    std::list<int> l1;
    std::vector<int> v1;

    foo(std::begin(l1), std::end(l1)); // OK
    foo(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1)); // OK

    std::vector<float> v2;
    foo(std::begin(v2), std::end(v2)); // Doesn't compile
}
```

---

**[Live demo](http://ideone.com/Lfj8yJ)**

**Note:**

- **If** `foo` needs to access specific member functions of the container (as noted by Deduplicator, this might happen for performance reasons), then you might need to stick with the `Container` argument :

**Example :** (Note the difference for getting at the `value_type`, as pointed by MooingDuck, this is required to make it work with arrays):

```
template <typename Container>
void foo(const Container& c)
{

    static_assert(std::is_same<int, std::iterator_type<decltype(std::begin(c))>::value_type>::value, "Invalid value type : must be int");

   // Use c member function(s)
}
```

Comment: Depends. Using iterators can inhibit use of the proper algorithm, like `map.find`.

Comment: @Deduplicator agreed, but here the OP has a non-member template function, so I don't think it applies.

Comment: @quantdev The answer is ok for C++11. However, it's worth noting that, since C++14 is here, concepts are the best way to constrain a type.

Comment: Oh, it applies. How do you know he could not possibly used specialized faster algorithms if he only had the container instead of useless iterators? Of course, his container-function should delegate to an iterator-function for the general case, when it does not apply.

Comment: @black Except concepts didn't make it into C++14

Comment: @Praetorian As far as I know, yes they did. At least, concepts lite did.

Comment: @black [You don't know very far then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387888/did-template-concepts-get-to-c14)

Comment: @Deduplicator yes I see. Note added !

Comment: @quantdev: container assert fails for arrays.  I prefer `std::iterator_type<decltype(std::begin(c))>::value_type`.

Comment: @MooingDuck : [works for me with arrays](http://ideone.com/Lfj8yJ) - but you definitely have a point

Comment: @MooingDuck: Is there any case in which that's better than `decltype(*std::begin(c))`?

Comment: @quantdev: the iterator form is perfect, that's why you got upvotes.  The `void foo(const Container& c)` fails for arrays though.

Comment: @MooingDuck aah I see, of course you're right. Editing.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I'm not 100% certain.  `std::vector<bool>::iterator` is pretty weird, so maybe.

Comment: @MooingDuck: To my mind, using that one is an error all by itself. It's a shame they never removed that specialization... Still, that one is too weird to contemplate.

Comment: @Deduplicator: the real shame is that neither C++11 nor C++14 even deprecated that atrocity… If they had we would possible have the chance to remove it in C++2X

Comment: `using std::begin;` then use raw `begin` to enable ADL on `begin`.

Answer (score 10):

STL containers have the `typedef` `value_type`, so you may use it.

Then you may forbid with `static_assert`:

```
template <typename Container>
void foo(const Container& )
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<int, typename Container::value_type>::value, "expect int type");
}
```

or via SFINAE

```
template <typename Container>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, typename Container::value_type>::value>::type
foo(const Container& )
{
}
```

Comment: Could you give an explanation, why/when this is to be favored over a purely template-based solution for the problem?

Comment: @S.H: `static_assert` give a better error message and SFINAE disables the non matching template and so is not part of overload (so you may add an other overload for float container for example).

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, using template template parameters

```
template<template<typename, typename...> class Container, typename... Params>
void foo(Container<int, Params...> const&)
{
  ...
}
```

This will match `vector`, `list` or `deque` as long the type of the elements in the container is `int`.

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/oOWNvR)

Answer (score 0):

Assumeing you want an iterable range:

```
template<class I>
using value_type_t=typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type;
```

Obsolete in C++14:

```
template<class T>using decay_t=typename std::decay<T>::type;
template<bool b,class T=void>using enable_if_t=typename std::enable_if<b,T>::type;
```

Then:

```
namespace adl_details{
  using std::begin;
 template<class C>using iterator_type=decay_t<decltype(begin(std::declval<C>()))>;
}
using adl_details::iterator_type;


template<class C>
enable_if_t<std::is_same<int, value_type_t<iterator_type_t<C>>>::value>
foo(C&& c){
}
```

has that property.